# TabPage freezing application

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a TabControl, with a few TabPages. What I am trying to do is change tabs, and have it call a richtextbox on a different tab. I will try to word the question better after code...

```
    void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name)
        {
            case "tabPage_ProdOrders":
                dostuff();
                break;
        }


        //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    void dostuff()
    {
        while (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage_ProdOrders"])
        {
            safeCall("testing...\n");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }

    delegate void SetTextCall(string s);

    public void safeCall(string s)
    {
        if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCall d = new SetTextCall(safeCall);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { s });
        }
        else this.richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format(":{0}:\n",s));
    }
```

I know it looks sloppy- sorry. So the richtextbox resides on tabpage "tabPage_DEV". What I am trying to have happen is when I change to tabpage "tabPage_ProdOrders" have it append text to the richtextbox that is on "tabPage_DEV". This is moreover a test to make sure everything runs smooth, what I eventually will have happening is once "tabPage_ProdOrders" is selected I will have a gridview bound to my database, and so long as that page is selected, it will refresh from the database every X seconds. The problem is that as soon as I select the "tabPage_ProdOrders" the whole app freezes. I am assuming this is due to the Thread.Sleep() that I have within the while loop (my assumption is that since that void is part of the windows from that when it is .Sleep() the whole form is .Sleep() correct? Any guidance on a work around would be stellar.

Comment: How would you expect to ever leave the `while` loop ?

Comment: sob- dur... ok I should make the while loop call something that determines the status of the while loop... something like while(method()){... sleep() }; and then in method() something like return (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage_ProdOrders"])? true:false; ... But I still feel like this would hang in the .sleep correct?

Comment: How will the Tab change? By user interaction? In that case please don't wait for it in a loop!! And why would you call sleep at all?? Just wondering: Could it be that you don't know about GUI programming at all? You react to the user and the GUI does all the waiting..

Comment: because it needs to be on a timed loop to refresh from the database- there are jobs running on database altering data all the time. My source is bound to that database. I need to refresh after X period of time as to not overload the DB w/ connections. If the user stays on this page for "forever" it needs to continue to update regardless of interaction from the user. Tab control is changed via user interaction.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having a thread spinning and doing this and then firing an event when data has changed for that grid to update- but maybe that is the best way to do so? It just felt like it should* be something so much more simplistic.

Comment: I see. Use a Timer then! You must not keep the Cpu running in circles inside a method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used similar to TaW's suggestions...

```
    delegate void populateProdOrders(DataTable dt);

    public void safePopulate(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            populateProdOrders d = new populateProdOrders(safePopulate);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { dt });
        }
        else this.dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        // stuff
        System.Timers.Timer refreshProdOrders = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        refreshProdOrders.Elapsed += refreshProdOrders_Elapsed;
        refreshProdOrders.AutoReset = true;
        refreshProdOrders.Enabled = true;

    }

    void refreshProdOrders_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //dostuff();
        var globes = SharedResourceVariables.globals;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(globes.SQLConn);
        using (conn)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("development_usp_viewProdductionOrders", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (cmd)
            {
                conn.Open();
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        safePopulate(dt);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a Timer to your form and code its Tick event to do all the DB stuff.

Change the dostuff method like this:

```
void dostuff()
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage_ProdOrders"])
    {
        dbTimer.Interval = 10000; // your interval in ms
        dbTimer.Start();
    }
    else dbTimer.Stop();

}
```

With Thread.Sleep(..) you send the current, that is the GUI thread to sleep. Suerely not what you want..

Comment: Yeah that is what I assumed was happening- I knew I was doing something stupid/wrong but wasn't seeing it. Thank you for pointing me to Timers accordingly. I did go with a timer on the form as it will be better for that tabPage to update regardless if user is on it or not. Thanks again! (and FWIW, no, I do not usually code GUI's)